# Scroll textarea upwards/downwards on clicking prev and next hyperlinks in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a hyperlinks "prev" "next".
Clicking on "next hyperlink should scroll textarea to next location. 
Clicking on "prev" hyperlink should scroll textarea to previous location.

The locations to jump in textarea are known e.g. line: 10, then line 40 , 50 , 70 , 101 , ....
textarea has a fixed height.

Comment: Does your textarea have static height? In that case, I'd go with  jQuery.scrollTop() function and set it based on value you want.. [http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pagination.
 I prefer using styled pagination with jquery-

http://flaviusmatis.github.com/simplePagination.js/#page-20

This will help you sure.
As per need you want to go next, you need to give position for your current text-block or you can use `margin` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :- http://jsfiddle.net/MCK8g/

```
$(function(){

    $("#prev").on("click",function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: -500 + window.pageYOffset }, 600);
    });

     $("#next").on("click",function(){
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 500 + window.pageYOffset }, 600);
    });
});
```

Change the factor "500" depending upon the required scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Googled, first hit..

```
function scrollToLine($textarea, lineNumber) {
  var lineHeight = parseInt($textarea.css('line-height'));
  $textarea.scrollTop(lineNumber * lineHeight);      
}
```

> https://makandracards.com/makandra/8247-scroll-a-textarea-to-a-given-line-with-jquery

(the solution is using jQuery)

as mentioned their it only works if the line-height is set in pixels,
if not, a link with a workaround is also given in the post, see

> [jQuery: scroll textarea to given position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458655/jquery-scroll-textarea-to-given-position)