# Textarea scroll bar

Tags: html, textarea

I want the following textarea to allow scrolling when the stuff inside text.txt fills up more than the textarea window. Also, I want it to auto scroll to the bottom of textarea field. Is this possible?

```
<textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" readonly="readonly" " rows="20">
      <?php
      //$date=date(dmY);
      $file = fopen("text.txt", "r");

      while(!feof($file)){
         echo fgets($file);
      }
      fclose($file);
    ?>
    </textarea>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The scroll bars appearing should be automatic. For the bottom to be focused automatically would require JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

This is the CSS that will make sure you get a vertical scrollbar when there is too much text in:

```
overflow: auto;
```

For scrolling to bottom of textarea, clearly you need JS for that.
See [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642353/dynamically-scrolling-a-textarea).

Comment: so this did not exactly work. the scroll bar goes to the bottom temporarily but then goes right back up to the top of the textarea. since i put it in a timer, it just oscillates between the bottom and the top of the textarea.

Comment: i just gave you answer for the scrollbar - i didn't give you answer for your scrolling-to-bottom problem, just pointed to a similar problem on SO (there are probably more like this).