# Autoscroll to bottom of textarea

Tags: c#, jquery, textarea, onchange, autoscroll

I have a textarea which is dynamicly changed in c# by doing this:

```
TextBox1.Text=(String)Application["chat"];
```

When the text is to big for the textarea, I would like the scroll to always be on the bottom. I have tried to do this in JS(jquery) with the change event.

```
$("#TextBox1").change(function () {
    alert("alert");
    // $('#TextBox1').scrollTop($('#TextBox1')[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

This is the code I use in Javascript. The problem is that the event does not occur, even if the text in the textarea is changed, which I have proven by debuging it with the alert which does not execute.

Comment: have you tried : http://stackoverflow.com/a/642373/395890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Though I still have no idea why change event does not fire.

Comment: If you are using jQuery why not use $ instead of document.getElementById?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this issue of your event not firing: If this is ASP.NET webforms, it's unlikely that the client-side id of your textbox (input) is TextBox1.

View source on the generated page and check what the ID renders as and update you JS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You sould use this code to scroll down the textarea to the bottom:

```
$("#TextBox1").scrollTop($("#TextBox1").height());​
```

If you would like to scroll down, when it's content changes, use this:

```
$("#TextBox1").change(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop($(this).height());​
});
```